# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia doesn't work on macos catalyst WKWebView

Tags: camera, wkwebview, getusermedia, mac-catalyst, mediadevices

I've got the following error on Mac Catalyst WKWebView:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia')`

macOS 13.5.1 (22G 90)
Safari 17.0 (18616.1.24.11.5, 18616)
UserAgent "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.0 Safari/605.1.15"

The same app works well on iOS.

I have added native checks for camera and microphone access. If they are not available, I make a request. After both are approved, checkboxes appear in the privacy settings of macOS. However, I still receive the same error. Interestingly, iOS does not have any access checks; the request is automatically initiated, presumably by Safari.

Comment: Did you solve the problem somehow? I have the same code that works on iOS but not on Mac. On Mac, `navigator.mediaDevices` is simply `undefined`.

Comment: I have the same issue and did not find any resolution.

Comment: I have not found any resolution yet.

Comment: @morgenshtern I posted a solution which works for me, could you check it out?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works for me:

```swift
config.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "mediaDevicesEnabled")
```

Where *config* is an instance of `WKWebViewConfiguration`